# RedHat CodeReady Container command: crc start -p .\pull-secret.txt execute failed

Tags: containers, openshift, redhat

I'm trying to setup CodeReady Container on my company laptop following RedHat document, but I got below error when I executed `crc start -p .\pull-secret.txt` command:

```
PS C:\lab\RedHatCRC> crc start -p .\pull-secret.txt
INFO Checking if crc-admin-helper executable is cached
INFO Checking for obsolete admin-helper executable
INFO Checking if running on a supported CPU architecture
INFO Checking minimum RAM requirements
INFO Checking if running in a shell with administrator rights
INFO Checking Windows 10 release
INFO Checking Windows edition
INFO Checking if Hyper-V is installed and operational
INFO Checking if crc-users group exists
INFO Checking if current user is in Hyper-V group and crc-users group
INFO Checking if Hyper-V service is enabled
INFO Checking if the Hyper-V virtual switch exists
INFO Found Virtual Switch to use: Default Switch
INFO Checking if admin-helper daemon is installed
WARN Preflight checks failed during `crc start`, please try to run `crc setup` first in case you haven't done so yet
Get "http://unix/version": open \\.\pipe\crc-admin-helper: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Then I have below debug:

```
PS C:\lab\RedHatCRC> crc setup --log-level debug
DEBU HTTP-PROXY: http://127.0.0.1:8080, HTTPS-PROXY: http://127.0.0.1:8080, NO-PROXY: 127.0.0.1,localhost,.bpshare.com, proxyCAFile:
DEBU CodeReady Containers version: 1.29.1+bc5f4409
DEBU Running 'crc setup'
INFO Checking if crc-admin-helper executable is cached
DEBU Running 'U:\.crc\bin\crc-admin-helper-windows.exe --version'
DEBU Found crc-admin-helper-windows.exe version 0.0.6
DEBU crc-admin-helper executable already cached
INFO Checking for obsolete admin-helper executable
DEBU Checking if an older admin-helper executable is installed
DEBU No older admin-helper executable found
INFO Checking if running on a supported CPU architecture
INFO Checking minimum RAM requirements
DEBU Total memory of system is 17005862912 bytes
INFO Checking if running in a shell with administrator rights
DEBU Running '$currentPrincipal = New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent());$currentPrincipal.IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)'
INFO Checking Windows 10 release
DEBU Running '(Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" -Name ReleaseId).ReleaseId'
INFO Checking Windows edition
DEBU Running '(Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion").EditionID'
DEBU Running on Windows Enterprise edition
INFO Checking if Hyper-V is installed and operational
DEBU Running '@(Get-Wmiobject Win32_ComputerSystem).HypervisorPresent'
DEBU Running '@(Get-Service vmms).Status'
INFO Checking if crc-users group exists
DEBU Running 'Get-LocalGroup -Name crc-users'
INFO Checking if current user is in Hyper-V group and crc-users group
DEBU Running 'Get-LocalGroupMember -Name crc-users -Member 'bpshare\user1''
DEBU Running '$sid = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier("S-1-5-32-578")
        @([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole($sid)'
INFO Checking if Hyper-V service is enabled
DEBU Running '@(Get-Service vmms).Status'
INFO Checking if the Hyper-V virtual switch exists
DEBU Running 'Get-VMSwitch crc | ForEach-Object { $_.Name }'
DEBU Command failed: exit status 1
DEBU stdout:
DEBU stderr: Get-VMSwitch : Hyper-V was unable to find a virtual switch with name "crc".
At line:1 char:43
+ $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; Get-VMSwitch crc | ForEach- ...
+                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (crc:String) [Get-VMSwitch], VirtualizationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidParameter,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.GetVMSwitch

DEBU Running '[Console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8; Get-VMSwitch -Id a59xr1m3-145j-asdf-poiu-tgvyu783651s | ForEach-Object { $_.Name }'
INFO Found Virtual Switch to use: Default Switch
INFO Checking if admin-helper daemon is installed
DEBU Get "http://unix/version": open \\.\pipe\crc-admin-helper: The system cannot find the file specified.
INFO Installing admin-helper daemon
INFO Will run as admin: install admin-helper daemon
DEBU Running 'C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\crcScripts737883291\runAsAdmin.ps1'
INFO Checking if CRC bundle is extracted in '$HOME/.crc'
INFO Checking if U:\.crc\cache\crc_hyperv_4.7.18.crcbundle exists
DEBU U:\.crc\cache\crc_hyperv_4.7.18.crcbundle exists
Your system is correctly setup for using CodeReady Containers, you can now run 'crc start' to start the OpenShift cluster
```

Then I checked the vmswitch on my laptop:

```
PS C:\lab\RedHatCRC> Get-VMSwitch

Name           SwitchType NetAdapterInterfaceDescription
----           ---------- ------------------------------
Default Switch Internal
```

Yes, there is no crc vmswitch. But there is no any hint from RedHat CodeReady document. Could someone help here?

Thanks in advance!

Other Info:

Host Name:                 Localhost

OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise

OS Version:                10.0.19042 N/A Build 19042

Total Physical Memory:     16,218 MB

crc version:

CodeReady Containers version: 1.29.1+bc5f4409

OpenShift version: 4.7.18 (embedded in executable)